# How do I write a perfect vue.js action to fetch data from server with proper error handling?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

```
export const fetchEnvironmentsData = ({ commit }, params) => {
    Vue.http.get('/environments', { params })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data) {
                commit('mutateUpdateEnvironmentData', data);
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            alert('Could not load data, Please try again later');
        });
};
```

How do I handle internal server error and empty response from server?

Comment: How would you like your application to behave in this situation? Obviously you don't want to use `alert()`.

Comment: I just want it to alert if there is an error or empty data for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const error = () => alert('Could not load data, Please try again later');

Vue.http.get('/environments', { params })
  .then(response => {
    const data = response.json();
    if (data) {
      commit('mutateUpdateEnvironmentData', data);
    } else {
      error();
    }
  }, error);
```

or

```js
Vue.http.get('/environments', { params })
  .then(response => response.json(), () => null)
  .then(data => {
    if (data) {
      commit('mutateUpdateEnvironmentData', data);
    } else {
      alert('Could not load data, Please try again later');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, Decade. But your code does not give the desired result